# PHP Variables not staying constant

Tags: php, session

I am making a little Hangman game, and I have some code:

```
 $_SESSION['b1'] = $_SESSION['word'][0];
```

The word is peach at the moment, so when I guess P, I get this:

p _ _ _ _

But, say I guess e afterwards, I get this.

_ e _ _ _

Is there a way I could make p stay there after it is guessed?

Comment: Use an array to store the guessed letters

Comment: `$_SESSION['b1'] .= $_SESSION['word'][0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you would like to change the `$n`. character to `$something`:

```
$_SESSION['b1'][$n] = $something;
```

In your case:

```
$_SESSION['b1'][1] = $_SESSION['word'][0];
```

Details:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr